# Perl vs Java hash table performance

Tags: java, perl, hash

am trying to compare performance on Perl and Java Hash table. In Perl, using hash and counting number of words on 100K words

Perl:

```
%words = ();
open FILE, "<", "bigfile" or die "Cannot open file: $!\n";
while(my $line = <FILE>){
  chomp( $line );   
  $line =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g;
  my @words = split /\n|\s+/, $line;    
  foreach my $w (@words){
      $words{$w}++; 
  }  

}
close FILE ;
for my $key ( sort( keys %words ) ) {
  print "$key : $words{ $key } \n";  
}
```

In Java:

```
    Map<String, Integer> wordsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner( new File( "bigfile") );
        while( sc.hasNextLine() ){
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            input = input.replaceAll( System.lineSeparator() , " " );
            String[] inputArray = input.split("\\s+");
            for(int i=0; i< inputArray.length ; i++ ){                  
                String r = inputArray[i].replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|[^\\p{ASCII}]+", ""); 
                if ( wordsMap.containsKey( r )){
                    int count = wordsMap.get( r );
                    wordsMap.put( r , count + 1 );
                }else {
                    wordsMap.put( r, 1);
                }
            }

        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException fnf ){
        fnf.printStackTrace();
    }

    Set <String> keys = wordsMap.keySet(); 
    TreeSet<String> sortedKeys = new TreeSet<String>(keys);

    for( String key: sortedKeys){
        System.out.printf("%-10s%10s\n" , key, wordsMap.get(key) );
    }
```

When i run the above 2 version, Perl seems to run faster. I read somewhere Java Hash is different from Perl's. Is there any way to optimize the Java version?

How I timed both, using Linux time.

```
#> time perl count.pl
real    0m0.316s
user    0m0.236s
sys     0m0.018s

#> time java count
real    0m1.434s
user    0m1.856s
sys     0m0.181s
```

Comment: How are you timing the snippets? Your Java benchmark is probably inaccurate.

Comment: hi, using System.nanoTime(). Actually when i run both, its rather obvious i have to wait for a bit longer on the Java version as compared to Perl's version. :)

Comment: And Perl? Please show us the benchmarking code as well.

Comment: @simbabque , on Perl, i just use linux time command. is that wrong way? thanks

Comment: You are not comparing hashmap performance.  In your loops you are also performing string manipulation.  Also, you did not warm up the JVM so your results have not given the JIT Compiler a chance to optimize your code.

You really should read up on micro benchmarks and redesign your test to only compare the hashmap performance.

Comment: I agree with @Dodd10x. In Perl, you can use a module called Benchmark.  http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html It lets you take timings for certain operations, or run different implementations of code against each other. There will be something similar in Java too.

Comment: Not only is Perl significantly faster on nontrivial regexes, you aren't even giving Java a fair chance by precompiling them.

Comment: is it because I have extra regex in Java , like [^\\p{ASCII}] ?

Comment: i removed the [^\\p{ASCII}]+ , but it isn't any faster than Perl, although is faster than before.

Comment: You should also at least specify tiered compilation, if not properly warming up.

Comment: I think using a lot of API like HashMap, treeset, set, etc may be the cause of the slowness?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, what do you mean by warm up, and how to do this warm up thingy. What is tiered compilation.? thanks

Comment: This is not a topic to explain in a comment. Google for "warm up JVM" and "HotSpot tiered compilation".

Comment: Are you seriously relying on `time` to measure JVM performance? Then cease right away: JVM is defeated by default. It is optimized for *long-running processes* and is notorious for slow startup times even after many years of optimization. My HotSpot takes about 200 ms just to print `Hello, world`, and proper warmup takes *seconds*.

Comment: wow, so many things to do just to optimize Java code. lol. i think the javac compiler should automatically do this warm up for us. Give me the impression that its not so intelligent. How come Perl interpreter doesn't need this kind of warm up process.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use a BufferedReader to read lines, it will be faster and the read
   line method already `chomps` the line separator.
2. Precompile regular expressions you use in loops (see `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile`)! Perl does this, of course.
3. Run the test on a file that is ten times the size.
4. Run the java program on a very small file 2 times, and a bigger file
   and compare the second timing with the third, so you get an idea how
   the start-up costs are. (Usually around 1/2 second.) Note also that
   the very first execution of a program will take longer, as the class
   files are not yet loaded in the file system cache. When you have
   many (several hundred) classes, it also pays off to pack them in a JAR.